# Making passes collect data

Tags: ios, iphone, passbook

I am trying to create passes for an event I currently use a website called passk.it. But I want to create a pass that asks the user what his name is and then the pass sends that information to me. Is this even possible? How do I approach this?

Comment: I don't know anything about passk.it, however if I had a website for creating passes which asked the user for their name before creating the pass, then I would have a script which would execute to store these details in a DB.

What I am saying is that it would not be the responsibility of the pass, it would be the responsibility of a server side script.

Comment: Using PassKit, you can use callbacks to automatically email you the details as soon as a pass is created.  Or you could create your own form as Nick suggests and then send the data to both yourself and the PassKit API to issue a pass.  If you have a PassKit account, send them an email and they can advise you how to achieve this.

Comment: How do I use callbacks with passkit?